# Find the oldest group of files and perform action

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am working on a script to find the oldest group of files and once found I need to be able to rename the extension on them.

Below is what I have so far

```psh
$DirectoryToScan = "C:\Temp"
$SubDirectories = @(gci -path $DirectoryToScan -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Fullname -notmatch 'Test'} | ? {$_.GetFiles().count -gt 0} | % {$_.FullName})
$Files = $SubDirectories | gci -ea SilentlyContinue | Select FullName, CreationTime | Sort CreationTime
```

What I get is the following

```
FullName                                                       CreationTime         
--------                                                       ------------         
C:\Temp\Firefox\Firefox\App\DefaultData\profile\bookmarks.html 4/6/2015 1:16:32 PM  
C:\Temp\Firefox\Firefox\App\DefaultData\profile\bookmarks.html 4/6/2015 1:16:32 PM  
C:\Temp\Firefox\Firefox\App\DefaultData\profile\bookmarks.html 4/6/2015 1:16:32 PM  
C:\Temp\Firefox\Firefox\Data\profile\bookmarks.html            4/6/2015 1:16:33 PM  
C:\Temp\Firefox\Firefox\Data\profile\bookmarks.html            4/6/2015 1:16:33 PM  
C:\Temp\Firefox\Firefox\help.html                              4/6/2015 1:16:34 PM  
C:\Temp\Folder1\IND0314C1AC04.htm                              7/10/2015 10:46:23 AM
```

My question is how would I select all the files with the oldest creationtime, but the kicker is I need to do it in batches so there may be files with a creationtime for multiple months

Example of the multiple months

```
FullName                  CreationTime
--------                  ------------
File1.htm                 4/1/2015 1:26:32 PM
File2.htm                 4/15/2015 10:46:14 AM
File3.htm                 5/1/2015 12:01:19 PM
File4.htm                 5/20/2015 1:15:39 AM
File5.htm                 7/10/2015 1:00:01 PM
```

So on the run of my script the first time it would only modify the files with a creationtime in the month of April, on the next run it would need to modify the files from March, etc

Comment: *"need to do it in batches so there may be files with a creationtime for multiple months"* - Please elaborate.

Comment: You need to formalize your file picking criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the files with the oldest date you could group the files by creation date, sort by date, and then select the first group (oldest date when sorting in ascending order):

```
$Files = $SubDirectories |
         gci -ea SilentlyContinue |
         Group-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date } |
         Sort-Object { Get-Date $_.Name } |
         Select-Object -First 1 -Expand Group |
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the info I was already aware of that I guess I am asking is there a way to detect what the oldest date is then only modify those files